# How to retrieve post parameters in symfony1.4 which are posted from External page

Tags: post, symfony-1.4

I am creating Rest API in symfony1.4 which is a symfony's action method. i'm trying to retrieve posted parameters from some page. i tried follwing lines of code.

```
public function someMethodAction( sfWebRequest $req ) {
  // $req->getPostParamater('param_name');
  // $req->getParameter('param_name');
  // these both lines returns null
}
```

give me a way to retrieve these post parameters in Symfony action. thanks !

Comment: How is the data being passed? Is it as a POST or GET parameter or as part of the body of the request?

Answer (score 0):

The functions `getParameter` and `getPostParameter` are methods of the request not the action. You should use:

```
$req->getParameter('param_name');
```

Comment: Are you sure that the parameters are passed in the correct form in the request?